# Create a map of images and click markers like Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I would like to create a map with my own images of an area
that will work like the Google maps. I would also like it to
have click-able markers and the ability to zoom (best if the
zoom refers to additional images).
I have been searching around the net and I found examples such as
OpenLayers, MapTile, OverScroll and SpryMap but nothing seems to
be able to do what I want.
Do you think that it is possible??

Thank you very much
Ion

Comment: It _is_ possible to develop an application like Google Maps (afterall, Google developed Google Maps). Unfortunately, beyond that, this isn't really the sort of question Stack Overflow is good at answering. Please check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information on what questions are appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: with all due respect the answers below are exactly what I'm looking for. After hours of searching on the Internet I thought it would be an appropriate place to expand my knowledge. I'm really sad that I get this kind of feedback for a simple question.

Comment: Although it's not a specific or coding question, I feel this question is "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". I was impressed with the Skyrim map and it fits in the google maps umbrella.

Answer (score 1):

This page seems to do what you want:

http://www.tamrielma.ps/skyrim/

It is a link from https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories

I just don't have much of a clue how to reproduce the Skyrim page :(

Answer (score 1):

An expert with the GoogleMaps API could make this for you, but I was able to find a service that works as an intermediary. I believe you can try it for free by uploading your images to that service, or you can pay a license fee to host everything on your own server.

http://www.maplib.net/

An example of a custom map which I believe does everything you are talking about: http://www.maplib.net/map.php?id=13985